# Star rating system - Connecting js with PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, system, rating

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dmv12rry/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on({
        mousemove: function(e){
            var $this = $(this);
            // Calculate number of stars
            var currentMousePosition = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
            var width = $this.width();
            var rounded = Math.round((currentMousePosition/width)*10);

            var starNumber = rounded/2;

            // Remove + add Classes + Store current rating
            $this.removeClass().addClass('stars s-' + starNumber).attr('data-rating', starNumber);
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            var $this = $(this); 
            $this.removeClass().addClass('stars s-' + $this.attr('data-default'));
        },
        click: function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            //Hide the current rating selector
            $this.replaceWith($('<div>', {
             'class': 'loading'
            }));

            // Send the request
            $.post('rating.php',{
                rating: $this.attr('data-rating')
            }, function(d){
                // Handle response
                if(d.result == 'error'){
                    alert(d.msg);
                } else {
                    $this.removeClass().addClass('stars s-' + d.rating).attr('data-default', d.rating)
                    $('.loading').replaceWith($this);
                }
            }, 'json');
        }
    }, '.stars');
});
```

And now I'm trying to connect this code with a MySQL database. The database is:

```
CREATE TABLE `rating` (
    `ratingid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `rating` FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ip` VARCHAR( 39 ) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`ip`)
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

And PHP file (rating.php) that connects:

```
<?php

// Error function that stops script processing with die
function error($message){
    $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'result' => 'error',
            'msg' => $message
        )
    );
    die($output);
}

// Round to the nearest 0.5
function roundToNearestHalf($number){
    return round($number * 2) / 2;  
}

// Instantiate database connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'XXX', 'XXX');

// Check that the connection worked
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    error('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// Verify that we have enough post items
if(count($_POST) > 1){
    error('Too many post items received.');
}

// Check that the rating was entered
if(!isset($_POST['rating']) || $_POST['rating'] == ''){
    error('No rating value provided.');
}

// Valid the rating amount that was entered.
if(!preg_match("/[0-5](?:\.5)/", $_POST['rating']) && $_POST['rating'] < 0 && $_POST['rating'] > 5){
    error('Invalid rating provided.');
}

// Check if the user has rated before
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT `ratingid`
    FROM `ratings`
    WHERE `ip` = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    error('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// Tell the user that they have voted already.
if($result->num_rows){
    error('That IP address has already voted, please try using another IP.');
}

// Store the user's rating.
$rating = $db->escape_string($_POST['rating']);

$sql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO `ratings`
    (`rating`, `ip`)
    VALUES ('{$rating}', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')
SQL;

if(!$db->query($sql)){
    error('Unable to insert rating to database [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// Get the average rating
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT AVG(`rating`) AS `rating`
    FROM `ratings`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    error('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// Fetch the average rating
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

$rating = $data['rating'];

// Output the average rating for the front end to handle
$output = json_encode(
    array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'rating' => roundToNearestHalf($rating)
    )
);
echo $output;
?>
```

But mozilla console tells me: "element not found". Referring to rating.php file: 94: 3.
Wear long time with this and I do not know that error may have. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Your rating table doesn't have a field for which item is being rated?

Comment: Well, right now I'm just testing whether receives data, as has solved this I will relate the table that I have with products with valuations. It may be that the error comes from not having them related to first?

Comment: What's on the line that the error message refers to?

Comment: End of the file: "?>" - "element not found" rating.php:93:3

Comment: Are you really seeing `?>` when you view the source in the browser? That means your server isn't configured correctly, it's not running PHP scripts.

Comment: I mean, when I have opened the page where the user can assess the record, when the user clicks on the stars to value appears in the browser console this error "not element found", if I click in rating.php: 94: 3, browser open the php file pointing "?>" (line 94)